# Using tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin gives "Module not found" error for "fs" and other standard modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I have spent half a day looking for a solution and trying everything I came across.
What I want is to use imports relative to my src folder by using an @src alias. Eg.
`import { GmailMgr } from '@src/google-api/GmailMgr';`

The most popular way to achieve this seems to be using https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin
Editing `tsconfig.json` like this makes vs code happy:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",        // path to output directory
    "sourceMap": true,          // allow sourcemap support
    "strictNullChecks": true,   // enable strict null checks as a best practice
    "module": "CommonJS",       // specify module code generation
    "jsx": "react",             // use typescript to transpile jsx to js
    "target": "es5",            // specify ECMAScript target version
    "allowJs": true,            // allow a partial TypeScript and JavaScript codebase
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*":["*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
      "./src/"
  ]
}
```

To inform webpack about the paths in tsconfig.js, I then added the `TsconfigPathsPlugin` to webpack.config.js as described in the readme:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: "./App.tsx",
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(t|j)sx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        enforce: "pre",
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "source-map-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    // changed from extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"],
    alias: {
      'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom',
    },
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
    port: 45011,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:45011/dist/",
    hotOnly: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  devtool: "source-map"
};
```

When I run `webpack --mode production`, I can see that the files that don't use node_modules but use this @src import style are compiled so it works but I use the google api packages in one file (`GmailMgr.ts` in the errors) and those rely on things like fs, child_process, net and tls and for each of them, I get an error like this:

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'D:\MartijnFiles\Documents\Programming\0502-crew\youtube4me\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\dist'
 @ ../node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js 16:30-44
 @ ../node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/index.js
 @ ../node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js
 @ ../node_modules/gaxios/build/src/index.js
 @ ../node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/transporters.js
 @ ../node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js
 @ ./google-api/GmailMgr.ts
 @ ./components/YTNotifications.tsx
 @ ./App.tsx
```

It looks like it's trying to find fs, etc. inside the folder of the module instead of looking for it by starting in the node_modules root. If I remove the tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin and paths, everything is fine but I have to stick to imports like `import { GmailMgr } from '../../../google-api/GmailMgr';`

P.S. I have tried `webpack-node-externals` and it works for the errors but this is for a website so I then get errors in the browser that require doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has started to dawn on me that webpack only has trouble with modules that require node to perform (eg. fs) and a browser won't be able to do. I suppose the google api modules are intended purely for backend (while you are able to use them perfectly if you include them using  in the html). I guess I'll have to split my app into front and back end.

**Update:** I was right in this and split it up. However, I did still use webpack for both, just with different configs. In the backend webpack, I then used target: 'node' which prevents anything that should come from node_modules from being packed.

Answer (score 3):

I encounter the same problem, but I don't think it's related to certain api.

I think it's a bug when using tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin with webpack5.(I suppose you are using webpack5)

I submitted a issue here: https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin/issues/60

Answer (score 1):

You may need to specify the full path to `src/`. Rather than using TsconfigPathsPlugin, I was able to resolve the issue by using the Webpack `alias` property in `resolve`, and using `path.resolve(...)` to my source directory.

In webpack.config.js:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ],
    alias: {
        '@src': path.resolve( __dirname, 'src' )
    },
},
```

For some reason using the full path worked, whereas using relative paths in webpack.config.js like `@src: './src'` did not. I suspect this is why TsconfigPathsPlugin didn't work as it was pulling the relative path from tsconfig.json.